# Cant pass variable to flask template

Tags: python, templates, flask, jinja2

Ive had a lot of trouble trying to pass a variable to a template in flask. I've read the docs and examples and I cant see what I am doing wrong.

The flask route "poll_request" below polls a dictionary in another python module to see if a pump is on or off. The route is currently accurately identifying when the dictionary says on or off when it prints "state" to the terminal.

I am sending an ajax request to poll the status of a pump and render the template with the correct variable. I am sending a get request to the flask route so that if a pump is "on" it renders the template with the variable "on" to the page or else the route will render with the variable "Off". The variable is printing and returning the correct value on the server side but it is not being put into the template when it is rendered. I've cleared the cache and close/open the page to see if it was a cache problem. Neither of areas in the template render the variable.  I am new to flask/jinja so any help would be great.

ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'poll_status',
    type: 'get',
})
```

flask route

```
@app.route("/poll_status")
def poll_status():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        x = current_user.get_id()
        if all(value == "off" for value in pubsub.pump_status.values()):
            print('all off')
            return render_template("main1.html", pump1="off")
        else:
            state = pubsub.pump_status['pump1']
            return render_template("main1.html", pump1=state)
    else:
        return redirect(url_for("log_in"))
```

html

```
<span class="border rounded pump_text" id="pump1_status"> {{  pump1 }} </span>
<p> {{ pump1 }} </p>
```

Comment: Hi johnny,  assuming you have a templates folder in the project structure, Are you able to render any other variable? When you can, add more information so the community can help you troubleshoot the app. [flask docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#rendering-templates)

Comment: ok thank you, I edited the question. Let me know if you need more information